# Uninstall Jetbrains toolbox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jetbrains-toolbox

I downloaded and installed JetBrains toolbox on Ubuntu. I want to uninstall it now. It is not listed in the UBUNTU SOFTWARE app.

How do I uninstall manually ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the article [How to uninstall Toolbox App?](https://toolbox-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001313270-How-to-uninstall-Toolbox-App) on Toolbox App Support:

> To uninstall Toolbox App on **Linux**:
>
> 1. Uninstall all applications installed in Toolbox App
> 2. Uncheck 'Run at login' in Toolbox App settings or remove `~/.config/autostart/jetbrains-toolbox.desktop`
> 3. Exit Toolbox App
> 4. Remove directory `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox` with all its contents
> 5. Remove file `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-toolbox.desktop`

Comment: Just wanted to make the correction for step 5. It should be `.local`:
`~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-toolbox.desktop`

Small, but less confusing in case some people aren't sure